# Trying to find complexity of the solution to the problem Power Sum

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

**Question->**  Find ways an Integer can be expressed as sum of n-th power of unique natural numbers

Example -> x = 100, n = 2

Output -> 100 = (10^2) OR (6^2 + 8^2) OR (1^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + 7^2) Hence total 3 possibilities

My code

```
private static int Helper(int x,int n,int current){   
        if(x==0)
            return 1;
        int answer = 0;
        int power = (int)Math.pow(current,n);
        if(power<=x){
        //Including current
            answer += Helper(x-power,n,current+1);
        //Excluding current
            answer += Helper(x,n,current+1);
        }
        return answer;
    }
public static int findCount(int x, int n) {
        return Helper(x,n,1);
    }
```

My Approach -
I am trying to find solutions by including the current natural number and excluding it. For the example above, the answer can contain 1 (1^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + 7^2) or not (10^2)

I am trying to analyze the time complexity of the code I have written. But neither am I able to write a recurrence relation nor construct a recursive tree with any pattern. Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is to use recursive backtracking, without using memoization(a concept of dynamic programming). So it is possible that you will be computing the same sub-problem repeatedly, i.e, the helper method gets called on the same x, n and current more than once. This can lead to an exponential runtime.

A better way is to use dynamic programming shown as the following. (Some comments are added).

A few notes here:

1. I am assuming that we will not have any integer overflow when computing x^n.
2. The powerToN method can be optimized to achieve O(logN) time using the concept of binary search. (x^n = x^ (n / 2) * x ^ (n / 2)). But in this problem n will not be big, so it does not matter.
3. The runtime is O(X * X^(1/n)), using this dynamic programming solution makes analyzing the runtime and space complexity fairly straightforward.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PowerSum
{
    public int findPowerSumWaysDp(int x, int n) {
        //O(X ^ (1 / n))
        List<Integer> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            int v = powerToN(i, n);
            if(v <= x) candidates.add(v);
            else break;
        }
        //find the number of ways to sum to x, in each way we can only use the same number once
        int k = candidates.size();
        if(k == 0) return 0;
        //dp[i][j]: the number of ways to sum to i with the first j numbers in candidates
        int[][] dp = new int[x + 1][k + 1];
        //for sum 0, there is always 1 way, that is to not pick any number.
        for(int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
            dp[0][i] = 1;
        }
        for(int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j <= x; j++) {
                //if we can use the current number, use it
                if(j >= candidates.get(i - 1)) {
                    dp[j][i] = dp[j][i] + dp[j - candidates.get(i - 1)][i - 1];
                }
                //we can always choose not to use the current number
                dp[j][i] = dp[j][i] + dp[j][i - 1];
            }
        }
        return dp[x][k];
    }

    private int powerToN(int x, int n) {
        int v = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            v *= x;
        }
        return v;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PowerSum powerSum = new PowerSum();
        int x = 100;
        int n = 2;
        System.out.println(powerSum.findPowerSumWaysDp(x, n));
    }
}
```